# jQuery - element not firing events after wrap

Tags: jquery, events, binding

When I dynamically create a div using jQuery, use it to wrap another element (using jQuery.wrap() method) and bind some events to the wrapper, they don't get triggered. Why?

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tqzzdu21/

```
var $wrapper = $('<div class="random-wrapper"></div>');   

$('.random-element').wrap($wrapper);


$wrapper.click(function(){
    alert('Sh*t happens ..');
});
```

Only the event listeners binded by delegate method get triggered, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't trigger events binded straight to the element instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because using [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) creates a clone of the passed element before it actually wraps it. So the actual element used in the wrap is not the same as the passed one(in this case it is not referred by `$wrapper`).

Instead if you access the parent of the target element and bind the event, it should work

```js
var $wrapper = $('<div class="random-wrapper"></div>');

$wrapper.click(function(){
  alert('before wrap - wrapper click');
});

$('.random-element').wrap($wrapper);

$wrapper.click(function(){
  alert('wrapper click');
});

$('.random-element').parent().click(function(){
  alert('parent click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="random-element">Lipsum</div>
```

[.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be
>   passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This
>   structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only
>   one inmost element. **A copy of this structure will be wrapped around
>   each of the elements in the set of matched elements.** This method
>   returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

Comment: Of course ... now I get it, thanks. BTW, it clones the binded event listeners too, so all I can just do is bind the events to the wrapper before calling wrap method.

Comment: @user10099 yes you could do that - updated the snippet to show that